# How do I pass a value to list-item

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want want to pass a value to list items but I don't know how.... This is what I want to achieve

```
<li class="list-group-item" value="" />Option 1</li>
```

> value="" the value should be anything I assign to it

The value should be added to the list with javascript or jquery anyone can go. I just want to assign this value so each list that will be added will have different functions onclick.... How do I do it

Comment: value attribute is not for list items

Comment: Pass value to where? Database, file, input, ...?

Comment: @FrazAbbas that's what I thought too but apparently it is if the list is an `ol`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/li (probably not what the OP is using it for though)

Comment: Maybe you are looking for a custom data attribute `data-*`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to add a special attribute to the list item, you should use `data-*` attributes. These comply with the HTML5 standard.

```
<li class="list-group-item" data-value="op1" />Option 1</li>
```

In your jQuery you can now get the value using the `data()` function.

```
var value = element.data("value");
```

If you want to assign a `data-*` value to an element, just pass a second parameter to the `data()` function.

```
element.data("value", "new value");
```